# How to modify the package name of the Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

As shown, I want to change 'web' to another name. What documents do I need to modify?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw52f.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is IntelliJ, just select the package (as in picture) and press `shift + F6`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the name you want to change and click on refactor and then rename,doing so will reflect the changes made where ever you have used it.